# Как заменить все тексты ошибок при аутентификации

Tags: laravel

При стандартной аутентификации (php artisan make:auth), при работе с формами входа, выхода, регистрации..., при некорректном вводе на странице выводятся описания ошибки на английском, как перезаписать эти сообщения на русский?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Изменение сообщений об ошибках
При необходимости вы можете задать свои сообщения об ошибках проверки ввода вместо изначальных. Для этого есть несколько способов. Во-первых, вы можете передать свои сообщения третьим аргументом метода Validator::make():

```
$messages = [
  'required' => 'Необходимо указать :attribute.',
];
```

$validator = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
В этом примере обозначение :attribute будет заменено именем проверяемого поля. Вы можете использовать и другие обозначения. Например:

```
$messages = [
  'same'    => ':attribute и :other должны совпадать.',
  'size'    => ':attribute должен быть равен :size.',
  'between' => ':attribute должен быть между :min и :max.',
  'in'      => ':attribute должен иметь один из следующих типов: :values',
];
```

Указание своего сообщения для конкретного атрибута

Иногда вам может понадобиться указать своё сообщения только для конкретного поля. Вы можете сделать это с помощью «точечной» записи. Сначала укажите имя атрибута, а затем правило:

```
$messages = [
  'email.required' => 'Нам надо знать ваш e-mail!',
];
```

Указание своих сообщений в языковых файлах

В большинстве случаев вы будете указывать свои сообщения в языковом файле, а не передавать их напрямую в Validator. Для этого добавьте свои сообщения в массив custom в языковом файле resources/lang/xx/validation.php:

```
PHP
'custom' => [
  'email' => [
    'required' => 'Нам надо знать ваш e-mail!',
  ],
],
```

Ссылка на доку https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#introduction

Comment: Добавьте ссылку на уже переведенный файл https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang/blob/master/src/ru/validation.php если не сложно

Answer (score 2):

Для этого вам надо добавить файл с переводами ошибок валидации (вы также можете изменить описание под ваши нужды).

Вот сам [файл](https://github.com/caouecs/Laravel-lang/blob/master/src/ru/validation.php)
Вам нужно расположить его по пути `resources/lang/ваша локаль` в данном случае будет папка `ru`. В итоге путь получится таким: `resources/lang/ru/validation.php`